# PHP Shows only first image from 4

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with my code, in my database (mysql), I have row information like this: 1, 4, 6, 7

```
$sql = "SELECT skins FROM table WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $arr = explode(",", $row["skins"]);

        foreach($arr as $array) {
            echo "<img src=skins/". $array .".png alt=''>" . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

In skins file I have skins with names, 1.png, 4.png and so on... This code transforms those numbers in array, and makes it seperate, but this code shows only first image, and the others shows that mini icon when its not showing image, and when I open it and look at it URL, I see URL like this: MYFOLDER/skins, and for example in second image it should be, MYFOLDER/skins/4.png, but it's not. Have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Dump your $arr and edit your question.

Comment: you missing the qoutes in `src=""`

Comment: As @Mihai suggests - if things are not working as you expect, show the simplest forms of the original data  - with `var_dump($row); var_dump($arr); ` just after the `explode()` line. It will likely be very obvious as to the issue.

Comment: echo "<img src='skins/$array.png' alt=' '><br>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose you image path in quotes

```
foreach($arr as $array) {
    echo "<img src='skins/". $array .".png' alt=''>" . "<br>";
}
```

and for remove space form $array

```
foreach($arr as $array) {
    echo "<img src='skins/".trim( $array) .".png' alt=''>" . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Also mention a space in `1, 4, 6, 7`

Comment: Wow, that actualy worked, I needed: trim($array), thanks.